# Is there a way to add a custom object section to the lead conversion page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lead-conversion

I would like to add a custom object section underneath the opportunity section.Is it possible to add a section.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as of now according to this idea:- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lLe0QAE

You can upvote for the Idea.

Comment: Can we replicate it use coding. If yes, Where can we find the component for the convert button page.

Comment: You can't reference the inbuilt components in your code. You have to write everything from scratch and overide the standard convert functionality. Even it is possible, it is not recomended.